# Julia showing candlestick plots with just one colour

Tags: julia, finance, candlestick-chart

I am unable to plot candlestick in Julia properly.
Here is a sample code:

```
using Plots
using Dates
using MarketData
using TimeSeries
gr()

ta = yahoo(:GOOG, YahooOpt(period1 = now() - Month(1)))
display(plot(ta, seriestype= :candlestick))
```

The output I get is below
[Candlestick Plot with one colour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kDJt.png)

How to ensure that I get red & green candles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would update your installation. I get two colors with Julia 1.8.0-beta3 and Plots version 1.29:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1p7J.png